# Как обрабатывать очень большие числа в с++?

Tags: c++, шифрование, длинная-арифметика

я пишу декстопный Qt шифровальщик с алгоритмом RSA, и на каком то из этапов мне приходится одно число возвести в степень второго, после чего происходит переполнение (лонг инт не спасает, значение растёт до неадекватных размером), после чего вылетает арифметик error. Как быть?

Comment: Использовать библиотеку с длинной арифметикой...

Comment: Не писать кастомную реализацию шифрования. Использовать готовые проверенные библиотеки.

Comment: Кстати, а вам точно надо именно результат возведения в степень? А не это число по какому-то вменяемому модулю (остаток от деления)? :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen - вполне возможно, задача состоит как раз в том, чтобы разобраться в реализации RSA. Автору вопроса: я вот интуитивно чувствую, что размер блока должен примерно соответствовать длинне ключа. я погуглил 5 мин, но не нашел явного подтверждения или опровержения, но, кажется, это должно быть так. Значит, Вам всё равно можно находиться в пределах 2048-битной 4096-битной арифметики

Comment: @Harry разумеется мне сам результат возведения непосредственно не требуется, но требуется остаток от деления числа возведённого в степень на заданное n, и вот тут уже начинаются проблемы.

Comment: @AlexeyTen хотелось бы думать что так, но при использовании возведения степени плюсовского и питоновского, первый плевался и ругался, второй же спокойно вывел результат

Comment: В питоне по умолчанию используется длинная целочисленная арифметика. Так что сравнение странное.

Comment: Проблемы потому, что вы спрашиваете "какой рукой держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей", а не "как забить гвоздь"...

Comment: Ну выведите, например, `print(154467**564643)`. Сколько времени займет? :)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вы работаете реально с не очень большими числами, раз проблема только в одном месте. А раз вам нужен результат по модулю — ну, взгляните на такой код, может, поможет?

```
//// Быстрое возведение в степень по модулю p (x^e mod p)
template<typename T, typename U, typename P,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value &&
                                     std::is_unsigned<P>::value &&
                                     std::is_unsigned<U>::value>
        >
T iqpow(T x, U e, P p)
{
    T res = static_cast<T>(1);
    x %= p;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res = (res*x)%p;
        x = (x*x)%p;
    }
    return res;
}
```

или с концептами

```
//// Быстрое возведение в степень по модулю p (x^e mod p)
template<integral T, unsigned_integral U, unsigned_integral P>
T iqpow(T x, U e, P p)
{
    T res = static_cast<T>(1);
    x %= p;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res = (res*x)%p;
        x = (x*x)%p;
    }
    return res;
}
```